# How to quote a list (for a scientific thesis)?

Tags: quotes, quotations, citation, scientific-language

I would like to quote a list verbatim.

Let's say this is the list, and it's originally from a book:

1. Mathematics is essential in many fields, including natural science, engineering, medicine, finance, and the social sciences.
2. Mathematicians engage in pure mathematics (mathematics for its own sake) without having any application in mind, but practical applications for what began as pure mathematics are often discovered later.
3. Mathematicians seek and use patterns to formulate new conjectures; they resolve the truth or falsity of such by mathematical proof.

Now I want to use it word by word for my thesis. Do I need to add quotation marks? If yes, where?

Comment: Theses often follow in-house style rules. Hopefully there is a document or a faculty advisor who can tell you the official answer for your school. Chances are, such a lengthy quote will be treated as a block quote. If the list is quite long it might be treated as a table or figure. Regardless, you must make the attribution clear or it will be plagiarism.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not such a document ...

Comment: I have a hard time imagining that "anything goes," but: Chicago Manual of Style says one should choose block quotes for lists (as well as any quote in which the source material has multiple paragraphs).